# Lion style non-modal alert example for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

Xcode4 introduced the gray-rounded-square style non-modal alerts that momentarily appear as required.  For an example, see 'Build Succeeded'.  iirc, this style of non-modal alert is also used elsewhere in Lion.

Now, also iirc, I believe I saw some official iPhone sample code showing how they recommend this effect is achieved in iPhone Apps, but I can't find it again.  I'd like to use in my App this to achieve a consistent style.

If someone recalls what I'm talking about, I'd appreciate a link. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not using Lion, could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: It's basically the overlay you get when you change the volume or screen brightness.

Comment: Ah, yes, so it is, I knew I'd seen it somewhere else, thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're talking about the bezel notification style? On iOS, I know [SSToolkit](http://sstoolk.it/) has support for such a display (under HUD View).

Another way: This uses [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD) and [provides sample code](http://blog.elucidcode.com/2011/03/using-a-hud-to-display-alerts-in-ios/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it using a momentary UIActivityIndicator. Something like [this](http://blog.emmerinc.be/index.php/tag/uiactivityindicator/)

EDIT: or [this](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/showing-message-over-iphone-keyboard.html)

EDIT: The idea is the same, a custom activity indicator. The above answer gives you some more specific links to your problem. But well it is an activity indicator you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. As mentioned, I do have my own implementation, but I'm sure I saw a Apple sample code implementation, and now I can't find it.